# Create a dataframe in hdfs from a python nested list

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, hdfs

Suppose that I have a big list which is like this:

```
lst = [['david', 'italy', 234], ['alice', 'france', 517], ['kim', 'japan', 673], ...]
```

I want to create a table with 3 columns name, country and num and save it as parquet in hdfs.

how can I do it with pyspark?

is it better to save this list as a csv file and load it directly in pyspark or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing with `python` into csv and loading it with `spark` is overkilling. You can directly create a DataFrame with `createDataFrame`:

```py
lst = [['david', 'italy', 234], ['alice', 'france', 517], ['kim', 'japan', 673]]

df = spark.createDataFrame(lst, ['name','country','num'])
df.show(3)

+-----+-------+---+
| name|country|num|
+-----+-------+---+
|david|  italy|234|
|alice| france|517|
|  kim|  japan|673|
+-----+-------+---+
```

And finally, write into `hdfs` with `df.write.parquet` method